# How to start Hotspot 2.0 registration and provision?

Tags: wifi, hotspot

On many materials of Passpoint and Hotspot 2.0 there is Register and Provision steps.

For example https://youtu.be/p4gDW6SJ150?t=845

But I cant find RFC or technical materials how it must be implemented.

I found offline provision https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/prov-wifi-profile-via-website for windows.

I need connection-time registration for Android and IOS